# Firebase FriendList Relation

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I need to show the status of my friends.
The solutions I found are below.

**Method 1:--------------------**

structure

```
friendlist:
  USER1_ID
    USER2_ID
      name: Soner
      id: USER2_ID

users:
  USER2
      name: Soner
      isonline : true
   USER1
      name: mahmut
      isonline: false
```

code

```
foreach(b as firebase.child(friendlist/USER1_ID) ){

firebase.ref("users").child(b).child(isonline).value();

//reult soner:online

 }
```

**Method 2-----------**

```
users:
   USER2
      name: Soner
      isonline : true
        friendlist
           USER1:USER1
   USER1
      name: mahmut
      isonline: false
      friendlist:
         USER2_ID:USER2_ID
```

code:

```
 firebase.ref(users).orderbychield(friendlist/UserId).equalto(USER1_ID);

//RESULT soner is online
```

Which method should I do?
which one is right?
Are there any suggestions?

Comment: Avoid asking `which one is right?` because there is never the **one right** solution. This makes your question opinion based and might be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll typically want to go with the first option, as one of the common recommendations for Firebase Realtime Database is to keep your data structure shallow and flat. I often explain this as: keep nodes of each entity type under their own top level list/node. Under the different top-level lists, your then use the same key, which allows you to join data from each list.

There are many reasons for this, so I'll include some links below, but a very immediate one here is that you might want show everyone's online status in the app, without allowing all users to read each other's friend list. Since Firebase always loads complete nodes, this would be impossible with your second data structure.

Also see:

- classic blog post [denormalization is normal](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html).
- the [documentation on structuring data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data), specifically the section on [best practices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure).
- client-side joins are not nearly as slow as many developers think, since [Firebase pipelines the requests over a single connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786).